# Cisco networking (difference between serial connection an copper straight through)

Tags: networking

What is the difference between using serial connections (ex: serial DTE, DCE) as compared to using copper straight through in a connection between routers? Is there any situations where serial connections are used as compared to copper straight through?

Comment: What do you refer to as "copper straight through"? Twisted-pair Ethernet without crossover? SFP+ DACs?

Comment: @Zac67 the copper straight though wire refers to RJ45 for T568A and T568B wiring standard

Comment: So you really mean "Ethernet over twisted pair".

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the difference between using serial connections (ex: serial DTE, DCE) as compared to using copper straight through [from comment: twisted-pair Ethernet] in a connection between routers?

Serial connections are generally point-to-point (P2P) and mostly unnumbered. Any data transmitted is received by the link partner. Serial links can use custom framing.

Ethernet requires addressing on the data link layer, ie. MAC addresses. Additionally, they use standard framing. Whether you use twisted-pair Ethernet with straight-through cabling or (mostly obsolete) crossovers is functionally irrelevant.

> Is there any situations where serial connections are used as compared to copper straight through?

Ethernet is nearly ubiquitous, but there can still be situations when a form of serial connection is preferred - for cost, stacking, scalability, form factor, historically, ...